# When can ResourceCounter.Quota Property be null?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am using search service statistics, and I am wondering in which scenarios I can  get null from **indexes** quota property?

when **serviceStatistics.Counters.IndexCounter.Quota** returns null?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.resourcecounter.quota?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_ResourceCounter_Quota

Answer (score 0):

From Search Service REST API [`Get Resource Statistics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/get-service-statistics#response) page, the quota will be null if if the service has unlimitied document counts.

[image]

See this link for more details as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#document-limits.

Comment: what about indexes quota?

Comment: As per the limits document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#index-limits), there are always a finite number of indexes that you can create.